# T-Sql transaction rollback local variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, transactions

In t-sql local variables are not transactional by default, I mean if we change variable value inside transaction scope and after that we rollback transaction variable won't be returned it's old value. 
Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: What about using 2 variables?

Comment: Hold initial value in 1 variable and getting it back after ROLLBACK?

Comment: Transactions protect database data, not program variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases are aimed to maintain data and the data is stored inside tables . The transactions are made to maintain data to make activities atomic inside database.Transactions only works on activities related to the tables like insert,update and delete in order to make it atomic.In your query you worked on variables and transaction not support rollback on variables because there is no data change inside database. Also take care about temp tables and table variables . Transaction rollback work on temp table and not work on table variables. So your query is true and engine does its work.